# How can I use the return from my function as an argument for another function in onAppear

Tags: swift

I am trying to use the result of the following function:

```
class GetRefresh: ObservableObject {
   let user = Auth.auth()
   var ref = Database.database().reference()
   @Published var refreshToken = ""
   func getRefresh() {
       ref.child("\(user.currentUser!.uid)").child("refreshUrl").getData { error, snapshot in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        let refreshUrl = snapshot.value as? String ?? "Unknown"
        let url = URL(string: refreshUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request) { (data, response, error) in
          if error != nil {
            print(error)
          } else {
            do {
              let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
              let token = parsedData["access_token"] as? String
              self.refreshToken = token!
            } catch let error as NSError {
              print(error)
            }
          }
        }.resume()
    }
  }
}
```

To pass as an argument to a `Async` service that is called in the onAppear of my view:

```
struct DevicesTab: View {
   @StateObject var callDevices = CallDevices()
   @StateObject var getRfrsh = GetRefresh()
   var ref: DatabaseReference!
   var body: some View {
       VStack(spacing: 0) {
           greeting.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
           messages
           Spacer()
       }
      .onAppear {
          getRfrsh.getRefresh()
          callDevices.getDevices(refreshToken: getRfrsh.refreshToken) //this fails
          }
      }
   }
```

The `callDevices.getDevices` is using the argument as a Header for its `URLRequest`.

If i hardcode the token in onAppear like:

```
.onAppear {
   getRfrsh.getRefresh()
   callDevices.getDevices(refreshToken: "HardcodedToken") //this works
  }
```

It works fine, albeit with a bit of a delay before the data is loaded but it works...
I am sure the function is returning correctly as I was able to print it in `GetRefresh`.

Comment: As url session task is asynchronous, the getRefresh method returns before token is setup by completion handler. If you want to wait you have to declare getRefresh as async and use the async version of urlTask. Then in view, you can use a Task to do await refresh, then get token. After this, ( doing async) , the token could be returned by getRefresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the reason for your code failing is you are not waiting for the network call to be completted before you call the next method.

Solution:

You could rework the code to be async. Or you could observe the changes of your `@Published`var and call `getDevices`.

```
.onChange(of: getRfrsh.refreshToken) { newValue in
            callDevices.getDevices(refreshToken: newValue)
        }
.onAppear {
// to avoid repeatitive refreshing
      if getRfrsh.refreshToken == ""{
         getRfrsh.getRefresh()}
      }
```

But be aware. This will call `getDevices`every time the value changes.

Comment: Anytime `getRefresh` is called it will return a new value by design, so will this just result in continuous calls for `getDevices`?

Comment: @KARL only if your token changes.

Comment: yeah anytime `getRefresh` is called the token will be different

Comment: @KARL edited to adress the problem